postgresql авторизация в django пользователь "postgres" не прошёл проверку подлинности (Ident)
хотел подключить postgresql к моему django приложению, только скачал postgresql. сделал всё по инструкциям из интернета:
изменил settings.py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '12345678',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


создал базу test и таблицу countries, заполнил её
изменял по-разному как писали в интернете файл var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
создавал пользователя давал права на бд
стоит fedora
ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 279, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 332, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 119, in connect
    raise last_ex.with_traceback(None)
psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: ВАЖНО:  пользователь "postgres" не прошёл проверку подлинности (Ident)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/azat/Документы/test/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/azat/Документы/test/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 107, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 118, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 89, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 63, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 320, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 296, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 278, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 279, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 332, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/azat/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 119, in connect
    raise last_ex.with_traceback(None)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection failed: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: ВАЖНО:  пользователь "postgres" не прошёл проверку подлинности (Ident)


pg_hba.conf:
...


# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d postgres
при команде SELECT * FROM "countries";
всё работает
возможно я не заметил, но таблица называется countries, а база данных видимо postgres
\l
                                              Список баз данных
    Имя    | Владелец | Кодировка | Провайдер локали | LC_COLLATE  |  LC_CTYPE   | локаль ICU | Правила ICU |     Права доступа     
-----------+----------+-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8      | libc             | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 |            |             | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8      | libc             | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 |            |             | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |                  |             |             |            |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8      | libc             | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 |            |             | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |                  |             |             |            |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 test      | postgres | UTF8      | libc             | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 |            |             | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |           |                  |             |             |            |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |           |                  |             |             |            |             | psqluser=CTc/postgres

\du+
                                         Список ролей
 Имя роли |                                Атрибуты                                 | Описание 
----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------
 postgres | Суперпользователь, Создаёт роли, Создаёт БД, Репликация, Пропускать RLS | 
 psqluser |                                                                         | 


когда я запускаю psql в консоли он работает до тех пор, пока я не укажу хост -h (пробовал и localhost, и 127.0.0.1)
при том:
pg_isready -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
127.0.0.1:5432 - принимает подключения

ничего не помогает подскажите пожалуйста

а что сам постгрес в логах говорит?

psql: ошибка: подключиться к серверу через сокет "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" не удалось: ВАЖНО:  роль "мой пользователь" не существует```
```psql -U postgres
psql: ошибка: подключиться к серверу через сокет "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" не удалось: ВАЖНО:  пользователь "postgres" не прошёл проверку подлинности (Peer)



это подключение через unix-socket. подключайтесь psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -u postgres

-u - параметра нет, если изменить  на -U, ошибка та же(```не удалось: ВАЖНО:  пользователь "postgres" не прошёл проверку подлинности (Ident)


да, пардон. вот так sudo -u postgres psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -d test. подозреваю что в базе test пользователя не существует

та же ошибка, но почему её не существует, я же ее создавал?

тогда стоит начать с того чтобы посмотреть какие есть базы и какие там привелегии (\l), какие есть пользователи и какие у них права (\du+)

я ввёл команду и добавил результат в сам вопрос, всё кажется так как я и установил в django

спросил значит я у gpt что не так, он сказал "Измените строку с local в вашем pg_hba.conf с peer на md5, чтобы использовать пароль для аутентификации."  и перезагрузить postgres командой sudo systemctl restart postgresql
это и решило мою проблему
